# I don't understand a behavior of binary numbers in Java

Tags: java, binary

I have the following code:

```
System.out.println(0b11111111);
System.out.println((byte) 0b11111111);
```

First row prints

> 255

and the second row prints

> -1

Please, can someone explain me why the results are different? How does `(byte)` casting change `0b11111110` number that it becomes `-1`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range of the `byte` type is -128 to 127. Since 255 is not a valid byte value, the binary number `11111111` is -1 when cast to byte.

If you don't cast `0b11111111` to `byte`, it remains (by default) an `int`, and 255 is a valid `int` value.